# Nodejs Environmental variables on Cpanel

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, environment-variables

I am trying to host my node and react app on godaddy.com c-panel and i don't know how to add my environmental variables. I have read that i have to add them to **.HTACCESS** file in public folder but it doesn't work.

this is the syntax:
SetEnv SOME_KEY "value"

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this article?

https://medium.com/@pampas93/host-your-node-js-app-on-shared-hosting-go-beyond-localhost-73ab923e6691

Go to your domain’s control panel. In most cases, it should be [domain URL]/cpanel.
After cloning the project from GitHub or sth, you can setup a node app on hosting.

[image: setup a node app]

Add environment variables manually in the block of **Environment Variables**.

I will be glad if this answer gives you some of the help.

Comment: the problem was the platform that i have got which had no env support. but your guide was the key to find the issue, thank you so much.

Comment: I am happy if it gave you a little help.